# Probably obvious problem in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, post, alert, javascript

I think this is just an obvious problem that I can't spot because I've been staring at code too long today. I have this callback as part of a JQuery POST:

```
                        function(data){
                                if(data == 'yes') {
                                        $('div.done').show();
                                } else if(data != 'yes') {
                                        $('div.error').show();
                                        alert(data);
                                }
                        });
```

I get the error div shown, yet in the alert all I get is yes. Anyone got any pointers (as I said, I imagine it's some really obvious mistake that I've missed).

Thanks

Comment: try this with firefox: `alert(data.toSource())`

Comment: are you sure that `data` has no whitespace at it's begin/end?

try adding `data = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');` before if statement.

Comment: Good suggestions, just thought I'd pipe in with if he's using jQuery he might as well use $.trim(data) ;).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The data.replace one didn't work, neither did $.trim(data). Just somebody, I can't seem to get that to work. What would I do, just put `javascript:alert(data.toSource())` in the URL bar?

Comment: @hrickards: no, I meant you should augment the alert call in the code you posted.  `Object.toString` is non-standard and I told you to run it in firefox which does have it.  what exactly does "can't seem to get that to work" mean?

Comment: @Just somebody: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you meant run it in firefox via javascript injection. It returns what you'd expect from the results of `alert(escape(data))` (see below) so removing the newline fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debuggng 101:

```
function (data) {
    alert(escape(data));
    if (data == 'yes') {
        $('div.done').show();
    } else if (data != 'yes') {
        $('div.error').show();
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That turned up `yes%0a`. Is that a line feed? Do you know how I could remove that, or even better stop PHP sending it? The only thing in my PHP file that sends anything is `echo 'yes';`.

Comment: %0A is a line feed you can do a regular expression: data.replace(/\n+$/);

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why that might be being sent?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I still have the same issue. `alert(escape(data));` still shows `yes%0a`.

Comment: Don't worry, I forgot the `data =` bit in front. That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: The reason PHP is sending an extra line feed is probably because you have whitespace after your closing `?>`. Delete the whitespace, or better yet, delete the entire closing tag (it's optional).

Comment: php scripts that don't generate HTML should not have the ending close tag to avoid problems like these (and others)